# Modifying HTML of a specific [products] shortcode instance

Tags: woocommerce

The HTML output of `[products]` shortcode can be changed using hooks as outlined in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`.

Is it possible to have the hook code only affect a specific shortcode output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `do_shortcode_tag` filter.

The [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/) (introduced in WordPress 4.7) filter allows you to modify the output of a shortcode before it gets mixed in with a post’s content.

Example:

```
function modify_shortcode_output( $output, $tag ) {
    if (  $tag === 'gallery'  ) {
        return $output."modified!";
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter('do_shortcode_tag', 'modify_shortcode_output', 10, 2);
```